# How to exit the registers list with q?

Tags: register

When using the `:oldfiles` command, I can easily exit the list with `q`.

When I use the `:registers` command, it says "Press ENTER or type command to continue". But I would like to exit the list with `q`, without entering into macro recording which is annoying. I don't like pressing `enter`.

Is there a native Vim way to exit the register list with `q`, just like the `:oldfiles` "pager" does? It would be nice to have a bit of consistency.

**EDIT**

To display registers, I actually do `:reg "0123456789`, which is a short output, so that's why Vim's "more-prompt pager" is not used (cf. `:h more-prompt`). I have a lot of `:oldfiles`, so that's why Vim's "more-prompt pager" is used in this case.

I want to be able to always hit `q` regardless of whether the output is short. Maybe there is a way to always force the "more-prompt pager"? Or to customize mappings for output windows? Worst case scenario I could pipe the output in a scratch buffer that has a custom `q` mapping, if there is no simpler solution.

Comment: See <https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25109/how-to-map-q-to-cr-for-the-hit-enter-prompt>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave in to the dark side and used some hacky Vimscript:

```
map <silent> '' :call DisplayRegisters()<cr>

function! DisplayRegisters()
  redir => output
  silent exe 'reg "0123456789'
  redir END
  new
  silent file [Registers]
  setlocal nonumber norelativenumber
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile nobuflisted nomodified
  silent put =output
  silent normal gg"_d2j
  exe 'resize ' . line('$')
  map <silent> <buffer> q :q<cr>
  map <silent> <buffer> <esc> q
endfunction
```

This allows me to see a short list of registers by typing `''`, and close it by typing `q`, just like I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is whether the whole list fits in the screen or not. If your screen is tall enough, the output of `:registers` will fit in the screen, and you will see the message “Press ENTER or type command to continue”. If the output of `:oldfiles` is long enough, you will need to scroll and will instead see the message “-- More --”.

Once you scroll to the end of the `:oldfiles` output, you will see the same behavior as with `:registers`, so Vim is being consistent.

In the output of `:registers` (or any time “Press ENTER or type command to continue” is shown), pressing <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, or <kbd>↑</kbd> will change the message to “-- More --” and you will be able to use <kbd>q</kbd> to quit the list. It’s probably not the answer you’re looking for, but it does help to explain to explain the behavior.

Comment: Makes sense, now I understand why this happens to me, since when I display registers I usually do `:reg "0123456789`, which has a short output.

Answer (score 2):

I can press `q` at `Press ENTER or type command to continue` to quit.

If that does not work for you, look at `:help press-return` - you can also use `<space>` to continue.

```
   Press ENTER or type command to continue

This message is given when there is something on the screen for you to read,
and the screen is about to be redrawn:
[..]

-> Press <Enter> or <Space> to redraw the screen and continue, without that
   key being used otherwise.
```

Comment: If you press q at `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, it will quit, but it will also begin recording a macro if you type a letter right away.