# How to map "q" to "<cr>" for the hit-enter prompt?

Tags: key-bindings

I regularly press `q` to exit the `-- more --` prompt in Vim.

I often mistakenly use this same key to exit the `hit-enter` prompt, which then starts recording a macro after a subsequent key is typed.

I'd like to map `q` to `<cr>` when the `hit-enter` prompt is shown.

I unsuccessfully tried the following mapping:

```
noremap <expr> q mode() ==# 'r' ? "\<cr>" : 'q'
```

However, `mode()` cannot be used in this context to check for the `hit-enter` prompt. As mentioned in the documentation, in most uses outside of `'statusline'` and `remote_expr`, `mode()` "always returns c or n."

Comment: From [`:help mode()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#mode%28%29): *"This is useful in the `'statusline'` option or when used with `remote_expr()`. In most other places it always returns `c` or `n`."*

Comment: @filbranden, Thanks! I've updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: The issue is not due to `mode()`; it can be used in an `<expr>` mapping. The issue is that mappings are ignored. From `:h pager`: `Note: The typed key is directly obtained from the terminal, it is not mapped and typeahead is ignored.` Slightly related [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2589).

Comment: @user938271, for the mapping I'm interested in, `mode()` would ideally return `r` for detecting the `hit-enter` prompt. However, I've verified that within the `<expr>` mapping, at the `hit-enter` prompt, `mode()` is returning `n`, as opposed to `r`. Additionally, I've verified that mappings are not ignored at the `hit-enter` prompt. For example, with the mapping `:noremap q :qall!<cr>`, vim exits when pressing `q` at the `hit-enter` prompt.

Comment: @user938271, it appears that mappings are ignored for the `-- more --` prompt, but the mapping I've attempted is for the `hit-enter` prompt.

Comment: Indeed my bad, I conflated the pager with the hit-enter prompt.

Comment: @DanielS. How about this? https://0x0.st/i2RX.txt

Comment: @user938271, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hack, but you could try this:

```
augroup hit_enter_prompt | au!
    if has('nvim')
        au CmdlineLeave : call s:hit_enter_prompt_no_recording()
    else
        au CmdlineLeave : call timer_start(0, {-> s:hit_enter_prompt_no_recording()})
    endif
augroup END
fu s:hit_enter_prompt_no_recording() abort
    if has('nvim')
        nno q <c-\><c-n>
        return timer_start(0, {-> execute('nunmap q', 'silent!')})
    endif
    if mode() isnot# 'r' | return | endif
    nno <expr> q execute('nunmap q', 'silent!')[-1]
    if exists('##SafeState')
        au SafeState * ++once sil! nunmap q
    else
        let q = {}
        let q.timer = timer_start(10, {-> mode() isnot# 'r' && q.nunmap()}, {'repeat': -1})
        fu q.nunmap() abort
            call timer_stop(self.timer)
            sil! nunmap q
        endfu
    endif
endfu
```